# NSXMLParser terminating due to NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

I am having trouble parsing an XML document to my project. I am getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key morph.'

Here is a snippet of my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CAS version="2.1" avatar="anna">
  <frames count="111" signCount="3">

<signStart index="0" gloss="mug" />

<frame index="0" isComplete="true" time="0" duration="20" boneCount="74"
    morphCount="51">
  <morph name="aaa" amount="0" />
  <morph name="ooo" amount="0" />
  <morph name="pout" amount="0" />
  <morph name="eee" amount="0" />
  <morph name="cgng" amount="0" />
```

Here is my code in my XMLParser.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class User;

@interface XMLParser : NSObject {
// an ad hoc string to hold element value
NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
// user object
User *user;
// array of user objects
NSMutableArray *times;
NSMutableArray *durations;
NSMutableArray *wheres;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) User *user;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *times;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *durations;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *wheres;

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser;

@end
```

and XMLParser.m

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "User.h"

@implementation XMLParser
@synthesize user, times, durations, wheres;

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser {
self = [super init];

if(self){
    // init array of user objects
    times       = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    durations   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//  wheres = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if(![elementName isEqual:@"frame"])
    return;
    NSLog(@"user element found – create a new instance of User class...");
    user = [[User alloc] init];

    //We do not have any attributes in the user elements, but if
    // you do, you can extract them here:
    NSString *time  = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"time"];
    NSString *duration = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"duration"];
    //NSString *where = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"where"];

    [times  addObject:time];
    [durations addObject:duration];
//      [wheres addObject:where];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if (!currentElementValue) {
    // init the ad hoc string with the value
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
} else {
    // append value to the ad hoc string
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}
NSLog(@"Processing value for : %@", string);
}  

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CAS"]) {
    // We reached the end of the XML document
    NSLog(@"names array: %@", times);
    NSLog(@"prices array: %@", durations);
//        NSLog(@"wheres array: %@", wheres);

    return;
}

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
    // We are done with user entry – add the parsed user
    // object to our user array
    //[users addObject:user];
    //user = nil;
} else {
    // The parser hit one of the element values.
    // This syntax is possible because User object
    // property names match the XML user element names
    [user setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
}    
currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

I assume it has something to do with my xml file, but am not 100% on the exact problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Offhand it looks like your User object doesn't actually have a property called 'morph'. Double check that you spelled it properly, and it's actually the right class at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Does your user class implement KVO for the key "morph"?

[What your User class needs to have to be considered KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172)

Can you post the interface and implementation of your User class? That would be handy.

[More about implementing KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was due to this line of code:

```
[user setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
```

I have temporarily removed it from my code until I understand why it is make the program throw an exception